# How to find scala documentation api from interpreter

Tags: scala, command, documentation

In `Python` we can do

```
help(function)
```

or

```
help(class)
```

to find the documentation of a particular `function` or `class`

How can we do that in `Scala` from the `scala interpreter` ?

Comment: What do you mean interpreter? like using scala REPL ?

Comment: Yes i mean the REPL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is not yet implemented.

You can read here https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/documentation-in-scala-shell/1652/4

Comment: If it helps, then you can check :)